# Is it possible to perform insert in gridview using boundfield in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I know how to perform edit and delete in gridview using boundfield,but 
is it possible to perform insert? in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible. Instead you can use the `FooterTemplate` with `Textbox` fields.

```
<FooterTemplate>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtemp_Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</FooterTemplate>
```

Comment: To Insert the new row from footer then use the Commandname as Add or any other
`<FooterTemplate>
     <asp:Button ID="Add" Text="Insert" CommandName="Add" runat="server" Height="30px" Width="120px" />
</FooterTemplate>`

In RowCommand:
 Get all textbox values by using the below snippit.

`if (e.CommandName=="Add")
{
TextBox txtemp_name = (TextBox)gvDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtemp_name");

}
`
Then atlast rebind the gridview to view the newly added row in gridview.

`gvDetails.DataSource = ds;
gvDetails.DataBind();`

It will be useful to you.